# CSS Animation not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am using a familiar script to make an text blinking with css. The text is blinking in every browser except Google Chrome. Including in the inspector view of Chrome I can see all the styles are there and they are not inherited. My link is inside Ul/li element If I put the link outside of if the blink effect is working but inside it it is not working. Here is part of my code:

```css
#container ul li:last-child a {
  float: right;
  animation-duration: 900ms;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  -webkit-animation: blink 900ms infinite;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
}
#container ul li a {
  font: bold 14px/32px"Lato", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  height: 32px;
  color: #becbb2;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
}
@keyframes blink {
  from {
    color: #ff0000;
  }
  to {
    color: #becbb2;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  from {
    color: #ff0000;
  }
  to {
    color: #becbb2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>

    <li>
      <a href="link.php"><span>Link</span></a>
    </li>
    <li style="float:right">
      <div class="pdf"><a href="pdf.pdf" target="_blank">Download</a>
      </div>
      <div class="pdf">
        <img src="images/1437596056_pdf.png">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Here is live version, the last link on the top menu should be blinking: http://crystalconsultant.eu/taen-gost/**

Comment: Download blinks (annoyingly) for me in Chrome. Is "link" the part not working?

Comment: Are you looking for the download text to blink, if so, it is working for me in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/weissman258/L7p8gydr/

Comment: Maybe off topic, but please don't use blinking text. This is bad for accessibility and won't pass some forms off validation tests.

Comment: the Jsfiddle is working, I have added a live version where I have it the same way and it is not working: http://crystalconsultant.eu/taen-gost/ the last link on the top menu

Comment: The external link is working just fine for me on Chrome (as it was the demo above).

Comment: strange, I guess it is some bug on my google chrome