# CSS animation not working in Chrome, working in Safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, animation, webkit

My issue is that I have a simple twitter sprite sheet that I'm using to animate on hover. But, in Chrome, while it scoots left on hover, it doesn't animate.

```
#tw:hover #twitter-bird {
    margin-left:-100px;
    -webkit-animation: fly 0.2s steps(3) 0 3;
    -moz-animation: fly 0.2s steps(3) 0 3;
    animation: fly 0.2s steps(3) 0 3;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fly {
from { background-position: 0 0; }
to { background-position: -450px 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fly {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: -450px 0; }
}

@keyframes fly {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: -450px 0; }
}
```

I have seen a few others posts about this:

1. [CSS Animation not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26588628/css-animation-not-working-in-chrome)
2. [CSS Animation not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596397/css-animation-not-working-in-chrome)
3. [css3 animation not working in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265096/css3-animation-not-working-in-chrome)
4. [CSS Animation not working on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939736/css-animation-not-working-on-chrome)

And most of the advice seems to be that "-webkit-" is needed to preface "animation: " in the css for chrome. But I've done that. What am I missing to get this bird to flap in chrome as well as it does in Safari and Firefox? I'll use Javascript or jQuery if I have to. Thank you!

Comment: After looking at this, just do it with JS, always , if you want to target another element while hovering on a different one, just stick to Js for that, all the tuts out there omit to tell people that they gonna run into browser inconsistencies like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your property

```
animation: fly 0.2s steps(3) 0 3;
```

is probably wrong. If you want to say that there is no delay, make it clearer and set the unit

```
animation: fly 0.2s steps(3) 0s 3;
```

But this would be equivalent to

```
animation: fly 0.2s steps(3) 3;
```

that is a more usual way to set it